# How to pass 1 parameter using Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater

Tags: javascript, ajax

**//From the main.php file**

var pars = 'test time';

new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('clock', 'clock.php', {   method: 'get',   frequency: 1, parameters: pars });

**//Inside the tiny clock.php file I cannot read the passed value.**

php

echo "@Init time  : ".$_GET["inittime"];

This is just about passing values to the file displayed in the 'clock' placeholder.

I will need to pass others.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the variable `sendData` instead of `parameters` according to the [perdiodical updater documentation](http://www.360innovate.co.uk/blog/2009/03/periodicalupdater-for-jquery/)

> sendData Array of values to be passed
>   to the page – e.g. {name: “John”,
>   greeting: “hello”}

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks "A" thats jQuery, i'm using Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater with prototype.js**

I did it like this in the end!

var clientClickTime=((new Date()).getTime())/1000;

var url="clock.php?clientClickTime="+clientClickTime;

new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('clock', url, {   method: 'get',   frequency: 1 });

Power to ya!